# Rich media on intent action

Tags: dialogflow-es

I can't realise, how to send to user rich messages instead of plain text. 
Somebody can help me with it?

[image: So, there i can place only plain text, but want to send rich media (images or stickers, for example)]

Answer (score 2):

At your intent, scroll all the way down to responses. Next to the default, there's a plus button where you can select for which platform you want to add rich messages. If you then go to the 'Add responses' you can select from the drop down menu what your rich response should have (madia, suggestion chips etc) and then add there all the information required.